# Informatica PowerCenter [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307] [DBPERSISTER_2002] The Repository Service failed to create the repository content

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am getting this error message while creating the MRS (Model Repository Service) in Informatica Powercenter 10.4:

> [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307][PERSISTENCECOMMON_0001] Internal error. The request processing failed.
> This was caused by [PERSISTENCEAPI_0307][DBPERSISTER_2002] The Repository Service failed to create the repository content.
> This was caused by A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@6f24bed2 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()**.

My Informatica and Oracle Database are installed on a Linux server.

I have created a `<MRS_User>` and granted these permissions:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY SEQUENCE, ALTER ANY SEQUENCE, DROP ANY SEQUENCE, SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO <MRS User>;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO <MRS_User>;
GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO <MRS User>;   
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO <MRS User>;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO <MRS User>;
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO <MRS User>;
```

I am getting this error message [MRS error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxEFW.png) and not able to understand where I am doing it wrong and what I am missing.

Could anyone help me resolve this issue?

Thanks,
BiraKishore

Comment: have you checked if you can connect to oracle DB from infa server. login to infa srver and use sqlplus to see if you can connect. This looks like hostname unreachable issue